# ASP.NET Textbox is losing focus after Postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a Textbox on Asp.Net page and it lose the focus after Postback. This page is under the MasterPage and MasterPage is using AjaxControlToolKit. It looks like AjaxControlToolKit update panel asynchronous post back is causing an issue.

waiting for help.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please reffer to the `How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` guide. The community will be glad to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I found answer, 
I have a Textbox in aspx page like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchUser" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Added the JavaScript in code behind. you can add it under Page_load or OnPreRender method per your flow need it

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setFocusOnControl", "$get('" + txtSampleNumber.ClientID + "').focus();$get('" + txtSearchUser.ClientID + "').select();", true);
 Page.SetFocus(txtSearchUser);
```

Comment: this is a "setFocusOnControl" dummy variable